# How can I prove that $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis

If we let $f(x) = x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),$ is $f'(x)$ continuous at $x_0=0$?? Since $f'(x) = 2x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),$ my reasining is it is not defined at 0. Therefore it is not continuous at 0. How can I prove it with $\epsilon-\delta$??

Comment: How do you define $f(0)$ in the first place?

Comment: @sidht I think it is clearly defined so that $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @sidht yeah.. the problem says that $f(0)=0$. I have to use this fact?? So $f'(0) = 0$??

Comment: To find $f'(0)$, you'll have to explicitly compute $$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} =\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^2 \sin(1/h)}{h}$$

Comment: Concentrate on the cos(1/x) term. The limit proof is similar to the proof that the limit of cos(t) as t goes to infinity does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the property of continuous functions that says

> continuous functions map convergent sequences to convergent sequences.

Now, consider the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}$ which converges to $0$. Check what happens with

$$ f'(x_n)=f'\left( \frac{1}{n\pi} \right). $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: First note that $\lim_{x\to 0} 2x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$, what can you say about   $\lim_{x\to0}-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$? (Consider approaching to zero using two different sequences.)

Comment: wait...How did you get the limit?? Isnt it 0??

Comment: @eChung00 You're right I had $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ in mind.